# Get the user address from the profile

Tags: android

Now, I'm trying to get the user address from the profile.

My source code is here

```
String[] projection ={ ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS };

Cursor mCursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(
        ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY),
        projection,
        null,
        null,
        null);
```

It succeeds to get the user profile though, "mCursor" gets all information from user profile.
So does anyone know to get the address from profile?

Answer (score 0):

I found how to get it by my self. "vnd.android.cursor.item/postal-address_v2" is the mimetype of address. And its type represents HOME, WORK, OTHER and CUSTOME. The source code below you can get the address from Profile. But take care that only OS4.00 and more has Profile class.

```
//Colums（address and its type）  
String[] projection = {
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FORMATTED_ADDRESS,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.TYPE,
};

profileCursor = null;

try{
    //make cursor
    profileCursor = getContentResolver().query(
    Uri.withAppendedPath(
    ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY),
    projection,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.MIMETYPE + " =? ",
    // This is the mymetype of address
    new String[]{"vnd.android.cursor.item/postal-address_v2"},
    null);

}catch(NoClassDefFoundError e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: how do you retrieve the address from the cursor ? I tried, but nothing appeared. I wrote : String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]));